# Azure Frontdoor - how do I hide backend url address?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I am using App Service with Frontdoor in Azure for faster latency.

However, I found that even though I mapped Frontdoor with custom domain,

It redirects to the original App Service url.

How do I only use the url I mapped with Frontdoor?

Answer (score 0):

That is how AFD works, it either forwards or redirects to your back end hosts, you can restrict direct access to your app services by using firewall on the hosts, and allowing only the service tag frontdoor-backend, that way you have ensured that all your connections come from AFD and the domain you mapped there.